# How to dismiss viewcontroller in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a library, and if the main app call my library its showing it, and download some data from server. But if the server has some error I would like to kill the library view, but it's not working
I have a delegate in the host app:

```
-(void)libraryResult:(NSString*)result{
NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
}
```

And I download data from server in the viewWillAppear method, and the download has a delegate method like this:

```
-(void)networkManagerError:(NSString *)error{
[hud hide:YES];
[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.delegate libraryResult:error];
}
```

I see in the log, that the app return to the main app, but the view don't change.
How to solve this? Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

`[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

To

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

try these..

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have VC1 which presents VC2, then inside VC2 at the corresponding event (say a Close button tap, or error from server etc.), you should call:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }]
```

If you set up things in such a way that VC1 is notified about those events that happen inside VC2, you can use:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, the 1st method is more preferred, as it's a better design practice, and contributes to more loose coupling between VC1 and VC2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fire a notification from your "library result" method if error occurred and add an observer to your current controller view.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:Remove_CurrentView object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(remove) name:Remove_CurrentView object:nil];

-(void)remove{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question.